# C# Error variable is unassigned in try-catch method?

Tags: c#, console-application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int lengthCountdown;
    print tell = new print();
    timer counter = new timer();
    Error invalidInput = new Error();
    tell.tell("Hi i am John");
    tell.tell("How long should the countdown last?");
    try
    {
        lengthCountdown = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        invalidInput.valueError();
    }
    counter.timing(lengthCountdown);
    tell.tell("That was a " + lengthCountdown + " second countdown");
}
```

It says that there is an Error at "lengthCountdown" in counter.timing. Error: 
"Use of unassigned local variable"... If I am not using the try-catch method it isn't showing the Error.

Comment: As a side not, I'd very strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, as early as possible.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have the try/catch block, you'd only ever reach the statement that *uses* `lengthCountdown` if the assignment had succeeded anyway.

If `int.Parse` or `Console.ReadLine()` throw a `FormatException`, you're currently catching that exception *and then proceeding*, despite the fact that no value will have been assigned to the `lengthCountdown` variable. The compiler is stopping you from trying to read the value of the variable without it having been assigned a value in your code.

It's not clear what you *want* to do when there's an error in user input, but proceeding with the rest of the code as if you have valid information (even after warning the user, or whatever `invalidInput.valueError()` does) is a bad idea. You *could* just give `lengthCountDown` an initial value at the point of declaration, but that's unlikely to be wise in this case.

Comment: To catch this issue right, he can use a int.TryParse in a while loop, where the successful parsing of the Console.ReadLine makes a break out of the loop. If the parsing goes wrong, the user should be get a message.

Comment: @SeanStayn: Possibly - if that's what they want to do. We don't really know; maybe they're happy to use a default value if the user enters invalid input... we just can't tell without more information. Either way I'd probably move the code into a separate method, so it's not breaking out of a loop but returning from the method - that's likely to be easier to follow.

Comment: I am a simple man: I see Jon Skeet as the author, I upvote it.

Comment: You [skeeted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9218) everyone else. Once again, ...I should rather say *as always*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the exception could be thrown from inside the `int.Parse()`, and the `lengthCountdown` wouldn't be assigned when the `try` block is exited.

Beyond the `try-catch`, you are accessing the variable, but there is an execution path through `int.Parse()` and directly into the `catch` block, in which the variable never receives a value.

To fix the problem, you have to assign an initial value in the first line (which misses the point), or to move the rest of the code which consumes the variable's value into the `try` block:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    print tell = new print();
    timer counter = new timer();
    Error invalidInput = new Error();
    tell.tell("Hi i am John");
    tell.tell("How long should the countdown last?");
    try
    {
        int lengthCountdown = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        counter.timing(lengthCountdown);
        tell.tell("That was a " + lengthCountdown + " second countdown");
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        invalidInput.valueError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to assign an initial value in the first line for lengthCountdown,
Try this snipt of code:

```
....
int lengthCountdown = 0;
....
```

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* the OP's code is failing, or what the effect of this is. While sometimes specifying an initial value is the right approach to avoiding this error, I doubt that it is in this case, but the OP won't know that without any more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is lying in this line of code where you only declaring

```
int lengthCountdown;
```

rather than assigning it as well.This is a compile time error rather that runtime errors that is catched by try-catch block.The Reason behind this is that value types needed to be assigned to a value before it's use, unlike reference types (classes,object) could have default values on it's creation.

What you need to do is assign it to a default value like(zero, or -1 or any value that is not arbitrary to your data range)

```
int lengthCountdown = 0;
```

You can use int.TryParse() instead of int.Parse() for safer conversion plus in this way you can even eliminate the try-catch block if it's merely used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the `try-catch` block, the Exception is thrown and the execution path leaves the method. So `counter.timing(lengthCountdown);`will never be reached.

With the `try-catch` block when an `FormatException` was thrown the exception catched. not rethrown, so that the execution is continued. But as the `Parse` failed before a value was assigned to `lengthCountdown` it would be now used without previously assigning a value.